# When I activated my enviroment after that my project is not starting showing as django not recoqnized even i installed python and django

Tags: python, django, anaconda

(base) C:\Users\shree>activate my

(my) C:\Users\shree>django --admin startproject learning_users
'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(my) C:\Users\shree>conda install django
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

(my) C:\Users\shree>django --admin startproject learning_users
'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

(my) C:\Users\shree>conda install python
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## All requested packages already installed.

(my) C:\Users\shree>django --admin startproject learning_users
'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mistyping the command, you should be typing

```
django-admin startproject learning_users .
```

You are currently calling django and then adding the flag --admin.

Might also be worth checking that you have Django installed in your virtual environment. With the venv activated type `pip freeze` and see if django is listed in the output.